# Detect theoretical perfect contour

Tags: .net, opencv, computer-vision, contour, emgucv

I guys,

I need detect the theoretical "perfect" contour of a imperfect element.
I see that with findContours function I can find the real contour but this isn't valid for my purpose.

[image: The example in image]

- Left element: Real image in grayscale.
- Right element: Theoretical form in white over black.

Can you help me?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Well, if you have the contour points (with findContours) then you can use RANSAC to fit an ellipse (if it is only ellipses) and then use this fitted ellipse to get a perfect contour

Comment: Thanks!!! But, can you send me an example or link with this?

Comment: you may use the [fitEllipse](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitellipse#fitellipse) from opencv, however this one is with least squares and not with RANSAC. For RANSAC is basically choosing random points testing if most of the points are inliers, and repeat until you get a desirable amount of inliers